# How do i get a EditText to display in my TextView?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Basically I'm trying to get my `EditText` with a `button` "Ok" to display what was written to show up in a `TextView` output.
Once the "Ok" `button` is pressed it get the text what was entered in the `EditText` and display in the `TextView`.

Been searching around and can't find anything that works. Can anyone help?

Edit: 
1) really appreciate the responds and help guys.
2) I think I"m asking this wrong.
What I'm trying to do is creating an option where the user can add their own Text into an activity.

Edit:
THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: its just a basic thing you have to do... you just have to get text from `EditText` on button-click and set that text to `TextView`..

Comment: Can you tell us what's problem in it? And show code.

Comment: textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString())

Comment: I'm very new to this...how would i write this up? and would this be in my onCreate method?

Comment: Did you try to google "android button click tutorial"? This is the simplest thing. You need to do more research :)

Comment: yes i have. I have a button, its waiting for me to tell it how to do something. I want it to display what was written in EditText. Just need to know how to code that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get Value from `EditText`

```
editText.getText().toString();
```

Set value to `TextView` in `Button Click`

```
textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
```

### Update:

implement `Button Onclick(...)` like

```
 Button negativeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonID);

 negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you be more detail with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use in your `Activity` in `OnCreate()`

```
    Button _ok =      (Button) findViewById(R.id.idofButton);
   TextView result = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.idofTextView);
    EditText entrytext = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.idofEditText);

   _ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         result .setText(entrytext .getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the EditText is named as `et`, TextView is named as `tv` and your Button is named a as `bt`..
Now declare your EditText, TextView and Button, below your class name like this:

```
public class EditToText extends Activity{
EditText et;
TextView tv;
Button bt;
------
------
 }
```

Now in your `onCreate` method and after `setContentView` do as mentioned below :

```
------
------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext); //EditText is defined as edittext in xml
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); //TextView is defined as textview in xml
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //Button is defined as button in xml

    //When button is clicked
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){   
    @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String txt = et.getText().toString(); //Get txt from et when button is clicked
            tv.setText(txt); //Set text extracted from et in tv

        } 
    }); 
}
------
------
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I'm fine,please go ahead!

Answer (score -1):

activity_mail.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.stackedittext.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ENTER TEXT HERE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.stackedittext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button ok;
    EditText edt;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = edt.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(msg);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Wrong In this??